# Porting Xamarin tutorial over to .NET MAUI

Tags: sql-server, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022, .net-maui

For my first ever mobile app project (which will eventually become an actual commercial project), I would like to try out .NET MAUI.  Unfortunately since it's still in pre-release, there is scarce documentation and no tutorial projects for it.  I did find the Xamarin tutorial here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/xamarin/hello-world-tutorial/intro

... but I don't think it's compatible with .NET MAUI.

Are there any other places where a newbie mobile developer who knows Visual Studio and C# can see an example app and be able to learn through creating an app on the level of, say, the [Contoso University web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0) I went through to learn ASP.NET Core with data model?  Can a Xamarin tutorial be tweaked to work with .NET MAUI?  If so, I would be happy to help with that process.  Now that I think about it, since I developed my web site based on the Contoso model, maybe I could help create a mobile app in .NET MAUI for that Contoso project?  Anyone at Microsoft interested?

Comment: this is the **first hit** I get from searching "maui tutorial" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-android.  It is followed by links to a dozen other MAUI specific tutorials

Comment: Also links about migrating from X Forms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/migrate , https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate+xamarin+forms+to+.net+maui

Comment: *"Anyone at Microsoft interested?"* - post as an issue at [github maui issues](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues) with label "area/docs". Maybe two issues - one about porting xamarin tutorials, the other about making a Contoso sample.

Comment: Thanks Jason, but if you go through that 'tutorial' you linked, you'll see all it is, is how to create a new MAUI project and run the example "Hello World" app that's created for you.  Not really a tutorial on using the software for a real-world project (nor are the other links below it).  Thanks ToolmakerSteve, I'll do that.